# Use non Discriminated Union types from F# in C#

Tags: f#

I have declared some data types in a F# library that I want to fill from C# code. The problem I encountered is that only DU's get "exported" as a class, consider this example file Test.fs:

```
module Test

type SimpleType = string

type SimpleList = string list

type SimpleDU =
     | A
     | B

type SimpleRecord = { Text : string }
```

I was confused at first when just referencing the F# project wouldn't allow me use the `SimpleType` and `SimpleList` types in C#. I looked at the resulting F# library with ILDasm and found only code for the `SimpleDU` and `SimpleRecord` type which are perfectly accessible in C# code.

Is there a way to "export" non DU types so they are usable in C# or do I have to declare every non DU type as an explicit record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions of

```
type SimpleType = string
type SimpleList = string list
```

are type abbreiviations which are eliminated during type checking and do not create new types. These are described in the specifition:

**8.3 Type Abbreviations**

> Type abbreviations define new names for other types. For example:
>
> ```
> type PairOfInt = int * int
> ```
>
> Type abbreviations are expanded and erased during compilation and do
>   not appear in the elaborated form of F# declarations, nor can they be
>   referred to or accessed at runtime.

Comment: I short that means if my F# library would export a function taking a SimpleType the C# callee would just see a string argument?

Comment: @prydain F# sees it as a string also, with the ability to use SimpleType wherever a string is needed. Try using a single case union `type SimpleType = SimpleType of string`. http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/